# Would the Pain Shriek of a Corpse Orgy affect other Corpse Orgies?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

The [Corpse Orgy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/corpse-orgy/) has an ability called Pain Shriek. If another Corpse Orgy is within range, does it take damage? They are smart enough to avoid damaging each other, so before I run the encounter, I want to know if they would hold off on Pain Shrieking in each others' presence.

Here is the description of Pain Shriek (Su):

> Twice per day, as a standard action, a corpse orgy can unleash a piercing shriek from the various heads captured in its form. This shriek deals 10d6 points of sonic damage to all creatures within a 40-foot radius around the corpse orgy. Affected creatures can make a DC 22 Fortitude save for half damage. Creatures that cannot hear do not take this damage. The save DC is Charisma-based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pain shriek affects “all creatures” in range except those “that cannot hear.” Nothing in the corpse orgy’s description indicates that it cannot hear, so it can, and thus would take damage from another corpse orgy’s pain shriek.

...though, to be fair, as written, the corpse orgy would also be subject to the damage from *its own pain shriek*. The corpse orgy is within a 40-foot radius around itself, and it is a creature. Nothing says it’s immune. However, this kind of oversight is infuriatingly common in Pathfinder (1e, anyway, don’t know about 2e), just as it was in D&D 3.5e that it was based on. So the corpse orgy probably doesn’t hurt itself—they’d probably highlight that if it were the case—but the fact that this isn’t explicitly covered by the rules does make you wonder what *else* was left out of the rules.

But anyway, as written, the corpse orgies affect one another.

Comment: 2e fixes it by allowing the creator of the effect to decide whether the source of any Emanation is effected.